# C++ 20 chrono: How to compare time_point with month_day?

Tags: c++, date, c++20, c++-chrono

Is there a modern and elegant way to determine if the *month* and *day* in a `time_point` variable match a given `month_day` variable?

For example, I want to know if today is Christmas. I have the following code:

```
#include <chrono>

bool IsTodayChristmas()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    constexpr month_day Christmas = {December / 25};
    auto Now = system_clock::now();

    // return Now == Christmas; // How to?
}
```

Modern and elegant: I mean if possible, I would prefer not to use old C types (something like `std::time_t` and `std::tm`) and string comparisons (something like `std::put_time`).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can convert `system_clock::now()` to a [`std::chrono::year_month_day`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day/year_month_day) type via a `std::chrono::sys_days`. In practice this might look something like

```cpp
#include <chrono>

bool IsTodayChristmas() {
    using namespace std::chrono;

    constexpr month_day Christmas = {December / 25};
    auto Now = year_month_day{floor<days>(system_clock::now())};

    // either
    return Now == Christmas / Now.year();
    // or
    return Now.month() / Now.day() == Christmas;
}
```

As Howard Hinnant pointed out, this will determine Christmas in UTC. You're more likely to be after Christmas in the local time zone: to do so, we must first transform `Now` into our local time zone: (Note `std::chrono::current_zone` is not yet provided by libstdc++ or libc++, as far as I can tell.)

```cpp
bool IsTodayChristmas() {
    using namespace std::chrono;

    constexpr month_day Christmas = {December / 25};
    auto Now_local = current_zone()->to_local(system_clock::now());
    auto Today = year_month_day{floor<days>(Now_local)};

    return Today == Christmas / Today.year();
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  But this determines if it is Christmas in UTC.  What about in the local time zone, or in Australia/Sydney?

Comment: @HowardHinnant ah, that's a good point; I assume you'd go through `local_days`, though I'm not entirely confident on that. If you do an answer I'll point to that instead!

Comment: I'm rooting for you! :-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant OK, added a note about using `current_zone`: does this look right to you?

Comment: I've noticed that `zoned_time(current_zone(), system_clock::now())` looks like it should work the same way (but through a zoned time instead of a local time). I'm not sure if one is preferable to the other, but if one is preferable here, some insight on that would be great as well.

Comment: Upvoted. :-)  Nice job.   Yes, working directly with the `time_zone` `current_zone()` is a good way to do this.  But using `zoned_time` is also a good way.  `zoned_time` is essentially a higher-level convenience API over working with `time_zone` directly.  But in this case doesn't buy that much convenience (nor does it cost much).  Either way, getting the current local time, and flooring it to days-precision is the correct way to get the current local date and compare it to Christmas.

Comment: If you need to know if it is Christmas in some place other than your local time, or UTC, then change `auto Now_local = current_zone()->to_local(system_clock::now());` to `auto Now_local = locate_zone("Australia/Sydney")->to_local(system_clock::now());` and everything else can stay the same.  In dealing with time, getting the question right is often harder than getting the answer right. :-)